# Select box multiselect option not able to clear using JQuery on Microsoft edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I am trying to clear all selected option using JQuery on Microsoft Edge browser.

Other than Edge it is working fine.

On Edge it is working but still Edge shows as selected.

If I hover on select box **after click on Clear All button** then it deselect all option

Below is my code.

HTML

```
<input type="button" id='clear' value="Clear All"/>


<select id="filter_value_1" style="width:200px;" multiple>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
</select>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#clear").click(function(){
    $("#filter_value_1 option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

  });
});
```

Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/c7jk6bpg/4/

Comment: Try with `.prop()` rather than `.attr()`.

Comment: Seems to be an Edge issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4490

Comment: Please see the comments specifically below the accepted answer of the marked duplicated. It does mention there to either use `.val([])` or `.prop("selected", false)`

Comment: @Nope this is also not working

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra `$("#filter_value_1").val([]);` didn't work in Edge?

Comment: I can confirm @alexP comment - tried it on an older version of Edge and it's working but not working on an updated one.

Comment: My version are **Microsoft Edge 41.16299.248.0** and **Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299**

Comment: @Nope **$("#filter_value_1").val([]);** also not working on edge

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Fair enough, removed duplicate.

Comment: `for (var i=0; i<select.options.length; ++i) {select.options[i].selected = false;}`. Have you tried what happens if you use this custom for-loop ([**https://jsfiddle.net/c7jk6bpg/39/**](https://jsfiddle.net/c7jk6bpg/39/)) ?

Comment: @myfunkyside this is also not working, behave same as prop('selected', false).

Comment: But it doesn't behave same as `$("#filter_value_1 option:selected").prop("selected",false);`. Where that one only iterates over the selected option, my custom for-loop will iterate over every option regardless of whether they're selected. Also it's not using jQuery, that might just do the trick for some reason... If it doesn't work okay, I just hope you tried it and didn't just assume it won't work because it's essentially based on the same function.

Comment: As a last resort you could try `$("#filter_value_1").trigger("mouseenter")` or `$("#filter_value_1").trigger("mouseover")`. Not the most ideal solution, but if all else fails...

Comment: @myfunkyside this is also not working, When I manually move cursor then only it gets deselected.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery focus() provides a workaround for this Edge bug.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clear").click(function(){
        $("#filter_value_1 option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#filter_value_1").focus(); // Edge bug workaround
    });
});
```

A potential drawback to this approach is that keyboard users get "focused" back into the select list. Normally, pressing an external button removes focus from the select list. With this workaround, pressing the Clear All button reactivates the select: subsequently pressing "A" selects option A. Users who navigate with the mouse might never notice. A keyboard user who Cleared All as prelude to choosing a better set of selections might appreciate the regained focus.